# VB2013 Get all Text fields and assign them to Variable

Tags: mysql, vb.net, string, variables

Now - this could me being lazy, but I have many Text fields on a form and I need access all .Text values in the form. Other then calling or assigning each one manually in the code, is there a way of adding the fields to a single Variable so I can access call them easier?

I have a long VERY long MySQL string at the moment, and it has taken me at least half hour to write it out and a further hour to fix the mistakes and correct stances. I am looking at doing the same again for another form, but I do not have to want to go through that all again.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Phill

Comment: Do your VERY long MySQL string include characters like `"`, `'`, `,` and `&`?

Comment: WinForms? Asp.net? or?

Comment: If you're being lazy (nothing wrong with that) you should consider using an OR-Mapper framework (EntityFramework) + WPF and follow the MVVM route.

Comment: =Steve this is pure Visual Basic, is VS2013 using the MySqlClient framework. =Filburt - could you explain that? Whats the MVVM Route? =Bjorn yes it does, its a full SQL command, with many '," and , No '&' though, does that help?

Comment: Would a function Do...While or For Each Loop be able to go through each text field and add the value to a Array variable? Any way that would work?

Comment: [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) is a pattern that relies very much on data binding and would allow you just by naming convention to bind data to your controls de-coupling GUI and code-behind. My personal favorite MVVM framework is [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/).